# I get a 404 page on /wp-admin but not wp-login but as soon as I login I get a 404 again

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

If I visit /wp-admin I get a 404 error.
If I go to wp-login.php I see the login screen.  If I login badly it errors, if I login correctly it redirects to /wp-admin and 404s again.

Things I've tried:

- Remove .htaccess
- Rename plugins to bak.plugins
- Rename individual plugin folders
- Turn on error reporting (a get an error about Oxygen builder which is a front end builder)
- Changing permissions of files/folders
- Clearing Cache & Cookies
- Checking options in DB to see if it is the right site URL (it is)
- Crying

I get an error for Oxygen builder saying:

Notice: Undefined index: button_priority in /home/***********/public_html/wp-content/plugins/oxygen/component-framework/api/oxygen.element.class.php on line 38

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem like this.

Did you change the salts in wp-config by any chance?

I changed them mid-production and the whole back-end just went haywire.

If you have a snapshot of an older wp-config, try that!

Comment: I did, I changed the db over to an old db.  But then I changed it back again.  Could that have caused it?

Answer (score 0):

This was a file/folders permission problem